# Small letter or capital letter for the word "aunt"

Tags: capitalization

> He requsted his **aunt** Mary.
>
> He requested his **Aunt** Mary.

I wonder whether I need to capitalize the word "aunt" in this sentence.

Comment: See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305107/capitalisation-of-uncle-and-aunt-in-phrases-like-your-u-uncle-bill

Answer (score 4):

"He requested his aunt Mary" is the correct answer. In this example "aunt" is not part of the proper noun title.

If however you were to say: "He requested Aunt Mary" then "Aunt" is capitalized because in that usage "Aunt" is part of the proper noun title of "Aunt Mary".